# React Routes protected routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am still a beginner in React programming and I am quite confused on how to do protected routing.

So, I have this in my **App.js**

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Route exact path="/" component={Loginscreen} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/upload" component={UploadScreen} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/materials" component={Materials} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

in which the landing page is the Log In Screen.

But what I want to do is that you can't visit /Upload, and /materials if you are not logged in.

Now, To be able to know that a person is logged in, I have this `onSubmit` func on **LogIn.js**

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var apiBaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login";
  var self = this;
  var payload={
      "email":this.state.email,
      "password":this.state.password
  }
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: false
  }

  axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status == 200){
        console.log("Login successful");
    }
    else if(response.status == 204){
        console.log("Username password do not match");
        alert("username password do not match")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Username does not exists");
        alert("Username does not exist");
    }
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
}
```

I was thinking what my `PrivateRoute` would look like that would check if the person is logged in according to the `response.status` in **Login.js**

Answer (score 1):

Create a `isLoggedIn` state variable in App.js and use it to decide whether or not to render other routes. Like this,

```
render() {
   let privateRoutes = null;
   if(this.state.isLoggedIn){
      privateRoutes =(
          <Route path="/upload" component={UploadScreen} />
          <Route path="/materials" component={Materials} />
      );
   }
   <Router>
     <div className="App">
       <Route exact path="/" component={Loginscreen} />
       {privateRoutes}
     </div>
   </Router>
}
```

Needless to say, `isLoggedIn` needs to be updated based on the value of `onSubmit` method

Comment: yep, that's correct, you will have to create a state variable and use that variable to guard the route.